# Mac equivalents for Linux ip command

Tags: macos, networking, android-emulator

I am trying to create a bridge between an Android emulator and the host system. I stumbled across [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191004/how-to-use-net-tap-with-android-sdk-emulator) question and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191743/344578) comment from 2018. The comment suggests using the Linux `ip` command to setup a bridge. Specifically, it suggests doing the following:

```
# ip addr flush dev enp0s20u1
# ip link set enp0s20u1 down
# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user $(whoami)
# ip link add br0 type bridge
# ip link set enp0s20u1 master br0
# ip link set tap0 master br0
# ip link set enp0s20u1 up
# ip link set tap0 up
# ip link set br0 up
```

Is there a way for me to do something equivalent on a Mac laptop without having to spin up a Linux VM? If so, what are the equivalent commands?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this? https://superuser.com/questions/687310/ip-command-in-mac-os-x-terminal

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the [iproute2mac](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/iproute2mac) brew package is limited and not fully compatible with [iproute2](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html). For example, [iproute2mac](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/iproute2mac) does not support `ip tuntap`.

Comment: have you tried the system preferences  > network UI https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh43557/mac

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using the **System settings**.
Go to **network**, then the three little dots to go to **Manage Interface Virtual** (rough translation from french, sry).

Once there, add a new bridge and choose what types of interfaces you want.